# How can I design a UI similar to the Android app switcher in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how difficult it will be to design the UI of my app in React Native. One of the main UI components I want is a sort of deck of cards that can be scrolled through (vertically) and selected (to display more details for the card).

A good example of this is the app switcher in plain Android

(See here: https://www1-lw.xda-cdn.com/files/2015/04/android-lollipop-recents-carousel-100526174-large.idge_.png).

I just want to know:

1. Is this feasible in React Native without a TON of effort?
2. If anyone has an idea about a general approach to this problem

Note: this should work on Android and iOS (the specific versions don't matter much - they can be fairly recent).

Comment: I ran into a similar case, could you share some example code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it is fairly simple. My first approach would be to render the items on top of each other, and use each one as a panResponder controlling the scroll of the entire deck on vertical movement. Using some math to position each item individually, you can make sure they move in a similar way (When on the top, they scroll very slowly, and as they approach the center, they scroll much faster). Making sure only to render around 6-7 items at a time (the ones that are visible), you shouldn't have many performance issues.
I would definitely recommend, if you don't have much experience with Animated and PanResponder, to practice some simpler examples until you get the hang of it.
This isn't hard. If you are familiar with these, it'll take you maybe a couple days max to accomplish this.

Comment: could you share a link of an example of this one?

Comment: Hi @brucelin, unfortunately I've never built this, and it would take a few hours to do. Currently I'd recommend `react-native-gesture-handler` and `react-native-reanimated` to build this, since this answer is a bit dated.